# Windows IoT - Bluetooth connection with Arduino

Tags: windows, bluetooth, arduino, iot

I was having some issues to connect my devices (Lumia 925 and Lumia 930) with Arduino, using Virtual Shields for Arduino. The app doesn't worked, frozed and crashed.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for that, was the baud rate of the bluetooth adaptor. Despite that the vendor's site tells that the correct baud rate is 9600, my code only worked when I put it in 34800 (i.e. shield.begin(34800);). I hope that this information help someone. 
Some sites says that the correct voltage is 3.3V. My device only worked in 5V.

Answer (score 0):

The app has been updated a couple times since October. Please try the updated Windows Store app also.